# Azure Service Bus C# Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I'm trying to send messages to a Service Bus queue using [Microsoft's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues) but I'm encountering errors when sending which are likely due to the company firewall. Using the default TransportType I receive this exception:

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it

I've tried appending `TransportType=AmqpWebSockets` to the connection string to use port 443 instead which has worked for others in a similar situation, but I encounter another exception:

> Unable to connect to the remote server

Any suggestions to try and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried validating your network doesn't block the communication? I.e. try running the code from a different network to see if AMQP over 5671 and WebSockets works elsewhere.